# Find Next() div based on Class, Test to see if Last Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to cycle through a series of `<div>` elements by using `has()` to determine if the element has a specific class, and then cycle through to the next element with `next()`.  I'm not using `hasClass()` because that returns `true/false` and I'm trying to store the selected element as a variable to use later in a function to test if it is the last.  I could be very well using the wrong selectors.

Here is the example mark-up:

```
<div class="hello"><p>Hello 1</p></div>
<div class="hello slide"><p>Hello 2</p></div>
<div class="hello"><p>Hello 3</p></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="next">NEXT ONE!</a>
```

And the example JQuery:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
var current = $('.hello').has('.slide');
var nextUp = $('.hello').has('.slide').next();

if( nextUp == '' ) {
    $('.hello:first').addClass('slide');
    $('.hello:last').removeClass('slide');
} else {
    $(nextUp).addClass('slide');
    $(current).removeClass('slide');
}
});
```

So, I want to see if the element with the class `.hello` has the class `.slide`, and if it does, find the `next()` sibling with the class `.hello`.

Then, my thought was if there is no `next()`, perform the action with the `:last` and `:first` element instead.  Please advise.

JS FIDDLE - http://jsfiddle.net/c4ZNm/

Comment: `has()` looks for descendents, when in doubt check the jQuery API http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code have some issues. First, `.has` check if the element has descendant that match the selector. You just need to combine the selector to `.hello.slide`.

```
var current = $('.hello.slide');
```

---

You can then reuse that variable to target the next element.

```
var nextUp = current.next('.hello');
```

---

You need to check the length to know if it found something, not an empty string.

```
 if( nextUp.length === 0)
```

---

You also don't need to wrap your `current` and `nextUp` in a jQuery element, they already are a jQuery element.

```
nextUp.addClass('slide');
current.removeClass('slide');
```

---

## Final code :

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var current = $('.hello.slide');
    var nextUp = current.next('.hello');
    
    if( nextUp.length === 0) {
        $('.hello:first').addClass('slide');
        $('.hello:last').removeClass('slide');
    } else {
        nextUp.addClass('slide');
        current.removeClass('slide');
    }
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c4ZNm/14/

Comment: @RCNeil Glad to help, if something is unclear, just ask!

Answer (score 2):

You would like to do these:

1. You can directly select using `.slide`.
2. Check the length of `nextUp` instead.

Try this, seems to be a workaround:

**JS**

```
$('.next').click(function() {
    var current = $('.slide');
    var nextUp = $('.slide').next('.hello');

    if( nextUp.length == 0 ) {
        $('div.hello:first').addClass('slide');
        $('div.hello:last').removeClass('slide');
    } 
    else {
        $(nextUp).addClass('slide');
        $(current).removeClass('slide');
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c4ZNm/15/)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I don't know why I didn't think to just select the element by the class I was after!

Answer (score 1):

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4ZNm/10/

instead of

```
$('.hello').has('.slide')
```

use

```
$('.hello.slide')
```

When there is no more next element, nextUp wont be '', its length will be 0.
I added count to count all .hello divs - 1 for indexication. because :last-child is your "a" tag element, not .hello div, so instead :nth-child(3) selector i added .eq(count) to be more dynamic.

Best regards